# Extract rows having the 11th column values lies between 2nd and 3nd of a second file if 1st column matches

Tags: python

Hello I have two files

file1 :

```
chr5 20311169 20311244 5 20311177 20311251 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936 255 + - 20311210.00
chr5 26610220 26610295 5 26610221 26610296 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1022:24155 255 + - 26610258.00
```

file2

```
chr5     20311200    20311220   Nucleosome:1    110    5.0    39.9    MainPeak    1.43492858    0.68583064
chr5    801    861    Nucleosome:2    70    1.0    5.4    MainPeak    0.17076187    0.806538035
chr5    1021    1091    Nucleosome:3    80    2.0    14.4    MainPeak    0.42430331    0.481579895
chr5    1181    1251    Nucleosome:4    80    1.0    7.5    MainPeak    0.1362587    0.32626102999999995
chr5    1361    1441    Nucleosome:5    90    2.0    14.7    MainPeak    0.34212933    0.291726595
chr5    1621    1801    Nucleosome:6    190    2.0    26.1    MainPeak:doublet    0.37546564    0.353192625
chr5    2011    2071    Nucleosome:7    70    1.0    5.7    MainPeak    0.15091517    0.396369735
chr5    2161    2331    Nucleosome:8    180    1.0    17.2    MainPeak    0.08865312    0.42133046500000004
chr5    2441    2561    Nucleosome:9    130    2.5    25.3    MainPeak    0.7368501    0.48843276
chr5    2781    2851    Nucleosome:10    80    3.0    17.5    MainPeak    0.80818501    1.303005
chr5    3271    3431    Nucleosome:11    170    3.0    34.5    MainPeak+Shoulder    0.72967697    1.348257495
chr5    3521    3571    Nucleosome:12    60    1.0    5.8    MainPeak    0.1880739    0.504429705
chr5    3641    3791    Nucleosome:13    160    1.0    12.5    MainPeak:doublet    0.10098579    0.363148215
```

I'm interested in printing rows from file 1 using a python code if the values of 11th column falls within the range start and end (2nd and 3rd columns )declared in the seconds file. As the position is only unique within a certain chromosome (chr) first it has to be tested if the chr's are identical... hence my desired output is

```
chr5 20311169 20311244 5 20311177 20311251 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936 255 + - 20311210.00
```

I have tried awk codes.. it works perfectly fine but they are very very slow !

The files I'm testing ( from which I need to print the rows are around 4 GB ).

I would highly appreciate if I can have some python code

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function to extract the Nth column from your text makes this reasonably straight-forward.  I've assumed when you say "Column 11" you mean, the 11 column counting from 1, not the index-11 column where the 1st item is index-0

Pseudo-Code:

```
Until there's no data left ~
    Read line1 from file1
    Read line2 from file2
    Extract Col11 from line1 as a real number
    Extract Col2 & Col3 from line2 as real numbers
    IF Col11 is within Col2 & Col3
        do something
```

Python Code:

```
import sys

# Given a space-separated row of data, return the Nth column as a real number
def getNthColumn(row, N):
    # Single-space the row, removing tabs, double-spaces etc.
    row = ' '.join(row.split())
    fields = row.split(' ')
    result = float(fields[N-1])   # fields are numbered 0->(N-1)
    #print("Returning column %d from [%s] -> %f" % (N, row, result))
    return result

if (len(sys.argv) == 3):
    fin1 = open(sys.argv[1], "rt")
    fin2 = open(sys.argv[2], "rt")  #TODO - handle file-not-found errors, etc.

    line1 = fin1.readline()
    line2 = fin2.readline()
    while (line1 != "" and line2 != ""):
        # Get the columns from the two lines
        f1_col11 = getNthColumn(line1, 11)
        f2_col2  = getNthColumn(line2,  2)
        f2_col3  = getNthColumn(line2,  3)  ### TODO handle errors
        # work out if it's a keeper
        # print("Is %f >= %f and %f <= %f" % (f1_col11, f2_col2, f1_col11, f2_col3))
        if (f1_col11 >= f2_col2 and f1_col11 <= f2_col3):
            print("MATCH: "+line1)
        else:
            print("NO-MATCH: "+line1)
        # Next rows
        line1 = fin1.readline()
        line2 = fin2.readline()
else:
    print("Give 2 files as arguments")
```

To be honest, if speed really is critical for this, it would be better to write it in a compiled language, e.g.: C/C++/Pascal, etc. etc.

EDIT: tested and working, added some debug print()s

EDIT2: Search file1-row against all rows in file2

```
import sys

# Hold all the file2 Columns
file2_col23 = []

# Given a space-separated row of data, return the Nth column as a real number
def getNthColumn(row, N):
    # Single-space the row, removing tabs, double-spaces etc.
    row = ' '.join(row.split())
    fields = row.split(' ')
    try:
        result = float(fields[N-1])   # fields are numbered 0->(N-1)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to fetch number column %d from [%s]" % (N, row))
        sys.exit(1)
    #print("Returning column %d from [%s] -> %f" % (N, row, result))
    return result

if (len(sys.argv) == 3):
    fin1 = open(sys.argv[1], "rt")
    fin2 = open(sys.argv[2], "rt")  #TODO - handle file-not-found errors, etc.

    # Load in the whole of file2, but just the column2 & column3
    # note the minimum col2 and maximum c3
    line2 = fin2.readline()
    min_c2 = None
    max_c3 = None
    while (line2 != ""):
        col2 = getNthColumn(line2, 2)
        col3 = getNthColumn(line2, 3)
        file2_col23.append( ( col2, col3 ) )
        # Note the min c2 and max c3 so we can quickly know if a search can
        # possible produce a result
        if (min_c2 == None or col2 < min_c2):
            min_c2 = col2
        if (max_c3 == None or col3 > max_c3):
            max_c3 = col3
        # next line
        line2 = fin2.readline().strip()

    # sort the columns to allow us to short-cut searching
    file2_col23.sort()


    line1 = fin1.readline()
    while (line1 != ""):
        col11 = getNthColumn(line1, 11)

        matched = False
        # is col11 is within any file2 row col2 or col3
        if (col11 >= min_c2 and col11 <= max_c3):   # make sure the search is worthwhile
            for col23 in file2_col23:
                (col2, col3) = col23
                if (col11 >= col2 and col11 <= col3):
                    matched = True
                    break

        if (matched == True):
            print("MATCH: "+str(line1))
        else:
            print("NO-MATCH: "+str(line1))

        # Next row
        line1 = fin1.readline()
else:
    print("Give 2 files as arguments")
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your reply ! I have copy pasted your code as it s in afile named test.py and run it using the following command  python test.py file1 file2 however I have got an output like this NO-MATCH: chr5 19776794 19776869 5 19776845 19776920 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1127:18467:28112 255 + - 19776857.00 however I;m sure that more than half of my input file falls within the range ( here I tested only chr5). Please help ! Should I change any parameter in the code you posted ? I'm sorry I'm new to python... there's no need for C/C++.. this code was very quick..

Comment: @Smiley - Add a few rows of test data to your question, and I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again... Here's few lines from file 1 : chr5 20311169 20311244 5 20311177 20311251 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936 255 + - 20311210.00
chr5 26610220 26610295 5 26610221 26610296 K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1022:24155 255 + - 26610258.00  and this for file two : 
chr5    121    221    Nucleosome:1    110    5.0    39.9    MainPeak    1.43492858    0.68583064
chr5    801    861    Nucleosome:2    70    1.0    5.4    MainPeak    0.17076187    0.806538035
chr5    1021    1091    Nucleosome:3    80    2.0    14.4    MainPeak    0.42430331    0.481579895

Comment: I will update my question example and this way it can be clear

Comment: I tested this with the given input.  It seemed to work.  If you uncomment the `print()` near the column comparison you can see it working, and why it made the decision it did.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested the code.. and I have found a problem in it.. the code only compares row by row from each file... so for example, if you move row 1 to the second place to make it row 2 and keep file 1 as it is in the provided dataset example...the output will be no match... I would highly appreciate if each value of column 11 in file 1 can be compared to all ranges of each row from file 2 ( 2nd and 3rd Column) as values from column 11 can be within the range of any row from file 2 . Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok please see above.  It would be interesting to work on a more useful data-structure that can short-circuit more of that search.  But I tried to present a simple and understandable solution.

Comment: The code is working perfectly fine now ! Thank you so much ! and it is really quick as well ! You were very helpful !

Comment: I have another final question please. if I have file similar to file 1 and a second file from which I want to filter rows having the 4th column identical to the 7th column of file 1 however they hold /1 and /2.. so basically if file 1 7th column K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936 and file 2 column four has K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936/1 and (  in a second row ) K00230:40:HNWJLBBXX:4:1101:1002:35936/2 how can I print these rows using python code. Thank you in advance.